# Unable to set up iCloud email on mail.app after accidentally deleting the ~/Library/Mail/ folder

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email

I accidentally deleted the Mail folder (at /Library) that contained a few sub-folders including one called V2. I did that hoping to do a fresh configuration of my iCloud and Live accounts.

However, when I tried reopening mail.app, it wouldn't restore the said folder. It does prompt me to configure a mailbox which I do, selecting iCloud in my System Preferences window but the mailbox still doesn't appear! The preferences menu option of mail.app is also disabled. Please advise if anything can be done to get it back to normal without a system reinstall!

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:

This is the first screen I get when opening Mail.app
[image: This is the first screen I get when opening Mail.app]

Then I select the first option to set up my iCloud account
[image: Then I select the first option to set up my iCloud account]

On the next screen, I check the Mail option and hit Add Account
[image: On the next screen, I check the Mail option and hit Add Account]

After all this, my ~/Library/Mail/V2 folder still looks like this (no mailbox created)
[image: After all this, my ~/Library/Mail/V2 folder still looks like this (no mailbox created)]

And the Preferences menu option in Mail.app is still disabled
[image: And the Preferences menu option in Mail.app is still disabled]

Here's a Console dump:
[image: Here's a Console dump:]

Comment: Deleting the accounts from System Preferences > Internet Accounts and readding them doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. Tried several times. :(

Comment: The Mail-Folder of your Account should be located in '~/Library/Mail' not '/Library/Mail' - i hope that was a Typo in your description. If you have manually created a 'Mail'-Folder in '~/Library' it could be a permission error. Quit Mail.app, start Console.app, then start Mail.app, check the Entries in Console.app and post the results. Perhaps there is a useful error message.

Comment: Yes, I had meant ~/Library/Mail and no, I didn't create the Mail folder manually. It was automatically created when I restarted Mail.app. I will post the Console output shortly...

Comment: @J.C.: Just posted the results given by Console. I see quite a handful of errors there...all Greek to me! :(

Comment: Instead of selecting "iCloud" when adding the account, try "Add Other Mail Account..." and follow the configuration steps.

Comment: @thankyour: Worked like a charm! Thank you soooooo much for the workaround. Could you please resubmit your comment as an answer so I could accept it and close the thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting "iCloud" when adding the account, try "Add Other Mail Account..." and follow the configuration steps. **Repost from comment for thread closure.**